# how to find checksum of a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, checksum

Hi i want to find a check sum of single string. what is the process of creating checksum and how can i create 8bit checksum of a given string. using C# .net like

```
 string this= "This is a test string";
```

how can I find checksum of this string using 8 bit checksum.

Comment: There is no standard "8bit checksum" in .NET. You could take 8 bits from an SHA hash pretty easily .. but I have no idea what the "requirements" really are.

Comment: And first you'll need to decide which encoding to use in order to convert the text data into binary data, as hashes and checksums usually work on binary input.

Comment: my requirment of check sum is it should be 32 digit integer and represented in hexadecimal. Check sum should be negative value of XOR of message. I need a step by step process to get this. I am unable to get understand this. I have no knowledge of checksums. Enconding not specified I can use any,

Comment: @user2864740 can you please share any example of SHA hash?

Comment: @RidaShahid No. But there are many examples found via a search. Note that taking bits from a crypto hash and a specific CRC/checksum are *not* strictly interchangeable in purpose. The "requirements" should be better specified. Please try some due-diligence searches for the *specific* "requirements" and general background knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of CRC8 - http://www.sanity-free.com/146/crc8_implementation_in_csharp.html
This is an implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

You can also find a bunch of other hash functions on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

And as mentioned in the comment, you could also use the lower/upper byte of one of the standard cryptography hash functions:

```
MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
return hash[0];
```